# AngularJS Form Validation - formName.$valid is always true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple form where the fields are dynamically generated through a directive called `field`. When I hit submit, the fields are validated and generate a valid class name such as `ng-invalid`, `ng-invalid-email`. But the class name of the form is always `ng-valid`. Any help would be much appreciated!

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw4A5EiyabO8UcvBg2Gi?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="app_controller">
    <form name="register" ng-submit="register_user()" novalidate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Username: </td>
          <td><field name="username" value="info"></field></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email: </td>
          <td><field name="email" value="info"></field></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="register.$invalid" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      Invalid: {{ register.$invalid }} <br />
      valid: {{ register.$valid }}
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('app_controller', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.info = {
    username: '',
    email: ''
  };

  $rootScope.meta = {
    "username": {
      type: "STRING",
      length: 255
    },
    "email": {
      type: "EMAIL",
      length: 255
    }
  };
});

app.directive('field', function($rootScope, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.field_name = $attrs.name;
      $scope.required = true;
      console.log($scope);
      var prepare_fields = function() {
        if ($rootScope.meta) {
          $scope.field = angular.copy($rootScope.meta[$attrs.name]);
        }

        var html = '';
        if ($scope.field.type === "STRING") {
          html = '<input type="text" name="' +$scope.field_name+ '" ng-model="value[field_name]" ng-required="required" />';
        } else if ($scope.field.type === "EMAIL") {
          html = '<input type="email" name="' +$scope.field_name+ '" ng-model="value[field_name]" ng-required="required" />';
        }

        $element.html($compile(html)($scope));
      };

      $rootScope.$watch('meta', prepare_fields);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compile `element.contents` after added content so just add bellow two lines

```
$element.html(html);
$compile($element.contents())($scope);
```

instead of

```
$element.html($compile(html)($scope));
```

that should be working :)

so final code in directive:

```
var html = '';
if ($scope.field.type === "STRING") {
    html = '<input type="text" name="' +$scope.field_name+ '" ng-model="value[field_name]" ng-required="required" />';
} else if ($scope.field.type === "EMAIL") {
    html = '<input type="email" name="' +$scope.field_name+ '" ng-model="value[field_name]" ng-required="required" />';
}

// $element.html($compile(html)($scope));
$element.html(html);
$compile($element.contents())($scope);
```

**N.B:** problem was you compiled a **string** not **element html**. so when compile *element contents* after modify *element* then it's working.

Comment: Awesome! I totally missed out that part :)